# Should OnTerminate be Synchronized?

Tags: delphi

`TThread` passes a Thread function called `ThreadProc` to `CreateThread` when the thread is created.
This is the `ThreadProc` used by `TThread`:

```
function ThreadProc(Thread: TThread): Integer;
var
  FreeThread: Boolean;
begin
  TThread.FCurrentThread := Thread;
{$IF Defined(MACOS)}
  if Thread.FSuspended then
    pthread_mutex_lock(Thread.FCreateSuspendedMutex);
{$ELSEIF Defined(LINUX)}
  if Thread.FSuspended then
    sem_wait(Thread.FCreateSuspendedSem);
{$ENDIF LINUX}
  try
    if not Thread.Terminated then
    try
      Thread.Execute;
    except
      Thread.FFatalException := AcquireExceptionObject;
    end;
  finally
    Result := Thread.FReturnValue;
    FreeThread := Thread.FFreeOnTerminate;
    Thread.DoTerminate;
    Thread.FFinished := True;
    SignalSyncEvent;
    if FreeThread then Thread.Free;
{$IF Defined(MSWINDOWS)}
    EndThread(Result);
{$ELSEIF Defined(POSIX)}
    // Directly call pthread_exit since EndThread will detach the thread causing
    // the pthread_join in TThread.WaitFor to fail.  Also, make sure the EndThreadProc
    // is called just like EndThread would do. EndThreadProc should not return
    // and call pthread_exit itself.
    if Assigned(EndThreadProc) then
      EndThreadProc(Result);
    pthread_exit(Result);
{$ENDIF POSIX}
  end;
end;
```

...and this is the code in `Thread.DoTerminate`:

```
procedure TThread.CallOnTerminate;
begin
  if Assigned(FOnTerminate) then FOnTerminate(Self);
end;

procedure TThread.DoTerminate;
begin
  if Assigned(FOnTerminate) then Synchronize(CallOnTerminate);
end;
```

So my question is; Should `OnTerminate` be Synchronized or not? Why would synchronization be default behaviour? Shouldn't it be left to the developer to decide?

I am asking because I cannot figure out why it would be synchronized and whether that behaviour would be the best in majority of cases.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `TThread` class arranges that the `OnTerminate` event handler is executed on the main thread as a convenience. It is most commonly used to allow the main thread to respond to the thread completing. In which case, it is most useful for the code to execute on the main thread. For example, it is common to clear references to the thread, or perform UI tasks when a thread terminates. By executing the event handler on the main thread, these tasks are automatically carried out on the correct thread.

If you wish to perform work in the thread at this point, you can override `DoTerminate` and place the work there.

In other words, you still have the choice. If you want code to run on the main thread, put it in an `OnTerminate` event handler. If you want code to run in the thread, override `DoTerminate`.

Comment: I noticed that it can be overriden and I do not mind doing that but I suppose I cannot see why synchronization would be the preferred default behaviour. I know it might sound like nitpicking on my part but it seemed odd to me and was wondering if the original author of the TThread code might have had a good reason for doing it and what the reason was.

Comment: @BlurrySterk since in Delphi event handlers are generally executed in the main thread, this is just consistent.

Comment: I personally do not consider TThread to be in the realm of Visually/VCL Related Components and seeing that the DoTerminate is called in the context of the thread and that one can create a thread from another a thread it just seems to me that Synchronization is not really required here as default behaviour.

Comment: All this off course is not important at all. I was just wondering.

Comment: @kobik Why would it not be?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite follow the question